# How to specify startup directory for WSL (Ubuntu) in ConEmu in Windows 10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, conemu

I have installed WSL2 with Windows 10 and downloaded and set up Ubuntu successfully.

I have installed and set up ConEmu terminal to run Ubuntu successfully.

But ConEmu opens Ubuntu in C:\Users\MyUsers

I want to start up in Linux (Ubuntu) Home\MyUsers\MyProjectFolder Directory

I tried to used each of these commands in ConEmu - Settings - Tasks - 6- Bash (or 7- Ubuntu) but none of them worked:

```
%windir%\system32\wsl.exe -cur_console:pm:/mnt --distribution Ubuntu -c "cd"
%windir%\system32\wsl.exe -cur_console:p -c "cd"
%windir%\system32\wsl.exe -cur_console:p -c "cd /home"
%windir%\system32\wsl.exe -cur_console:pm:/mnt --distribution Ubuntu -c "~"
set "PATH=%ConEmuBaseDirShort%\wsl;%PATH%" & %ConEmuBaseDirShort%\conemu-cyg-64.exe --wsl -cur_console:pm:/mnt -C "~"
wsl.exe -cur_console:pm:/mnt -C "~"
```

Comment: It looks like the answer that I just commented on has (just) been deleted.  In the comments there, you asked about changing to something like `/home/MyUsers/myproject`, but in the question body here, you said, *"I want to start up in Linux (Ubuntu) `Home\MyUsers` Directory."*  Can you clarify which one you want?  Is it both?  Sometimes you want to start in your home directory, but for another ConEmu task, you want to start in `~/myproject`?  Or is it just one or the other?

Comment: Hi @NotTheDr01ds, sorry for the confusion. Ideally I want to start in /home/MyUsers/MyProject. I updated my question details. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Short Answer

Set up a ConEmu task with either:

- `%windir%\system32\wsl.exe -cur_console:pm:/mnt --cd \\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\MyUser\MyProjectFolder`
- `-new_console:d:\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\MyUser\MyProjectFolder %windir%\system32\wsl.exe -cur_console:pm:/mnt`

### Details

*For completeness, I'm going to repeat the information from the previous answer that was deleted for starters.  Even if it doesn't directly answer your (updated) question, it is still good to have here as a reference.*

There are multiple techniques for specifying the starting directory for a WSL instance:

- You can launch directly to the WSL user's home directory using the (at this time, still [undocumented](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/reference#wslexe)) `wsl ~` shortcut.
- You can launch to a specified directory using the (also undocumented) `wsl --cd <WindowsDirectory>` commandline.  Note that this takes a Windows-style path to the directory, as opposed to a Linux path.  For instance, `wsl --cd C:\`.  To use a path inside the WSL instance, you can use the Windows' `\\wsl$\<distroname>\path`.  So your `/home/myuser/myproject` would become `wsl --cd \\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\myuser\myproject` (assuming that your distribution/instance name is "Ubuntu").
- You can set the directory in the parent process before starting the WSL instance.  WSL will launch into the current directory by default.  For instance, from PowerShell:

  ```
  PS> Set-Location C:\ # a.k.a. "cd C:\"
  PS> wsl
  /mnt/c$ # Now inside WSL shell
  ```

  ConEmu apparently uses the Windows `%userprofile%` as the starting directory for new tasks, which is why you end up in `C:\Users\MyUser` by default.  This is also why the second option above (asking ConEmu to set the starting directory) works.
- Not recommended:  `cd` to the directory in the shell startup config (e.g. `.bashrc`).  Not recommended since it removes the ability to use any of the other options if you ever want to start in a different directory.  The previous two techniques are much more flexible.
- Not recommended: You could also start an "outer" shell in the ConEmu task that does the `cd` command and then executes a new "inner" subshell (or even replaces itself with an `exec`'d shell.  E.g.:

  ```
  %windir%\system32\wsl.exe -cur_console:pm:/mnt --exec sh -c "cd /home/myuser/myproject; exec bash"
  ```

  It's not a *bad* way to do it necessarily; just that it feels like a waste sometimes to start two shells.  The first two techniques above are just better.  But this version *can* have it's uses.  For instance, I often start a WSL instance this way in Windows Terminal so that I set some environment variables in `sh` before launching into `tmux`, which then launches the `fish` shell in each window.

Comment: Tks. I set the task to %windir%\system32\wsl.exe -cur_console:pm:/mnt --cd \\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\myuser\myfolder and it worked.

Comment: For others interested, if you want to set up multiple tabs, just do like this: TAB1: %windir%\system32\wsl.exe -cur_console:pm:/mnt --cd \\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\myuser\myfolder TAB2: %windir%\system32\wsl.exe -new_console:s50H -cur_console:pm:/mnt --cd \\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\myuser\myfolder